# How to check whether dropbox item is selected?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have a mysql database with two tables:

```
table1 (id, name, emailid)
table2 (id, email)
```

- `emailid` is a relationship to `table2.id`

I'm trying to make an html form that lists the contents of table1 with a dropdown box for the user to select the email field. The email field is populated with `<options>` from `table2`.

My question is: how do I check what value is already selected for `emailid` and make that the already selected item in the dropbox when the form loads with `selected="selected"`?

I've gotten one solution to work already but I don't think it is the proper way to do it and was looking for the best practices method.

The way I am currently doing it will only work with one item pulled from `table1` but not if there are more than 1.

Here is my code so far:

This is where I get the data to make the form:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT table1.id as table1id, table1.name, table2.id as table2id
        FROM table1
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.emailid = table2.id
        WHERE table1.id = {$id}"; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
$items1 = array('table1id' => $row['table1id'] 
                'name' => $row['table1.name'] 
                'table2id' => $row['table2id']); 

$sql = "SELECT id, email FROM table2"; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $items2[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 
                 'email' => $row['email'], 
                 'selected' => ($row['id'] == $items1['table2id']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : ''); 
}
?>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<tr> 
    <td><?php echo $items1['name']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="table1id" value="<?php echo $items1['table1id']; ?>" />
        <?php echo $items1['table1id']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <select name="email"> 
        <?php foreach ($items2 as $item2): ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $item2['id']; ?>"<?php echo $item2['selected']; ?>>
            <?php echo $item2['email']; ?></option> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

This is how the form is updated:

```
<?php
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['table1id']); 
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 

$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET emailid = {$email} WHERE id = {$id}"; 
?>
```

Comment: are table1 and table2s' `id` primary key?

Comment: yes table1 PK is id and table2 PK is id. table1.table2id is populated with table2.id so that i can detect what email it is

Comment: Do you want a single query for this?

Comment: I've edited the OP and put in my current code. As you can see it will work. However, it will only work for one record from table1 and I'm not sure if it is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
Killed that other stuff now that you have code up.

```
// Lets make our table2 the primary so we can organize our values in the $items array.
$sql = "SELECT table1.id as table1id, table1.name, table2.id as table2id, table2.email 
    FROM table2
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.emailid = table1.id";
    // Do you need this WHERE?  I'm thinking not.
    // WHERE table1.id = {$id}";  
$items = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  // This will get set every time through the loop, but this is ok.
  // You can check to see if its set and then set or not set.
  $items[$row['table1id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
  // We will keep appending email values here to the table1id array.
  $items[$row['table1id']]['emails'][] = $row['email'];
}
```

Lets do the HTML markup now that we have all the items in a nice array for us.

```
<?php foreach($items as $id => $item): ?>    
<tr> 
  <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
  // Do you really need this hidden field?
  <td><input type="hidden" name="table1id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><?php echo $id; ?></td>
  <td>
    // Updated this to be unique for each id iteration.
    <select name="email_<?php echo $id; ?>">
    // Might want to consider a is_array() check on this value.
    <?php foreach ($item['email'] as $email): ?>
        <?php $selected = $email == $_POST['email_'. $id] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $email; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>>
        <?php echo $email; ?></option> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </td> 
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have not tested this so it may not work as a copy and paste.  But I think this is can get you going correctly now.

Comment: If you look at the OP Comments, `table2`.`id` is Primary Key~ so you are fetching one row max with your query~~~

Comment: Hmm is he wanting a single query?

Comment: i'm not entirely clear what he wants~ It looks like table2 is just a big pool of all e-mail addresses, and then he assignes them to individual rows from table1